# JavaScript: get distance from the top of the page to any tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

All web pages has a vertical height but height of long pages could overflows out of page. For example, the web page has a lot of `<p>` tags and some the tags owerfloved. I wonder how to get distance or space from the top of the page to `<p>` tags. 
      Notice here so some `<p>` tag's maybe overflowed downside, should not be a problem in this case.
      Another detail is maybe page is overflow to up upside. Should not be zero or minus value of the distance. So value of distances never change when page is scrolled or overflowed.
      How to get the distances? (My script returning `getBoundingClientRect()` object, I want to get the distance of object)

[image]

> webpage is scrolled;

[image]

Comment: I am not certain of your question. You have options:<br />

Comment: edited question, there are many detaild about question. You don't understand where?

Comment: You could use `document.getElementByTagName('p')[0].scrollTop` to get the value you require. You can write another function to change it's negative value to positive.

Comment: I am using `getBoundingClientRect()`, scrollTop not working.

Comment: Because containers can expand with content, I have never seen code to programmatically measure the pixel distance from the top left (x=0, y=0) corner of the page to any tag. The DOM may store this value but I have not seen any code to extract those values. "getBoundingClientRect()" would get you an object, not a tag.

Comment: I think you've caused confusion by stating `page` ... what you mean is a element's relation to the `viewport` not the page, correct?

Comment: do you mean something like `el.getBoundingClientRect().top+window.pageYOffset` ? if so... well you've got it now...

Comment: yes solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `document.getElementByTagName('p')[number].offsetTop` to get the value you require. You can write another function to change it's negative value to positive (if any such case arises).

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (key in p) {
  var textnode = document.createElement('span');
  textnode.id = 'scrollVal-' + key;
  textnode.style.color = 'red';
  textnode.innerHTML = p[key].offsetTop;
  p[key].innerHTML += textnode.outerHTML;
}

/*window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  for (key in p) {
    if (p[key].children) {
      p[key].children[0].innerHTML = p[key].offsetTop - document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop;
    }
  }
})*/
```

```html
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
<p>
  The Blender is a 10,000 pound explosive. It is carried in planes and dropped at heights of 30,000 ft. or higher. It creates such a crater that in 1907 it was ruled unfit for military use. Since then many rebel forces have tried using these to wipe the
  United States of America off the maps for good - but failed horribly.
</p>
```

Comment: you got me wrong me, edited question. Offsettop values does not changing so they are constant because they are associated with the upper side.

Comment: If you comment out the `scroll` event listener it will be just fine then. I updated my answer. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

If you check my fiddle you can see that it's possible to calculate the distance to the `viewport` by subtracting the viewport height from the offset value of the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/spbb14j5/1

```
$(window).on( "scroll", function() {

    var $y = $(".y"),
        $y2 = $(".y2"),
        $el = $(".element"),
        elh = $el.height(),
        wy = $(window).scrollTop(),
        wh = $(window).height(),
        eloffset = $el.offset().top;

    // distance to top of viewport
    var distToTop = eloffset - (wy);

    // distance to bottom of viewport
    var distToBottom = eloffset - (wy + wh);

    if ( distToTop >= (0 - elh) && distToBottom <= 0 ) {
        // Element is partially in viewport
    } else { 
        // Element is not in viewport
    }

});
```